# Why is a ThinkPad running Ubuntu 16.04 and Plex Media Server bringing down my entire LAN?

Tags: networking, thinkpad, plex

I'm running Plex Media Server 0.9.16.6 on a ThinkPad running Ubuntu 16.04.

I haven't timed it, but it seems like this happens every two weeks or so:

All of the devices on the LAN lose connectivity with the internet, and each other.

When this happens, I find the ThinkPad unresponsive (screen won't turn on/wake up).

If I unplug ethernet from the laptop, everything else on the LAN immediately starts working again. I then reboot the ThinkPad and everything is fine. Upon reboot I get a crash report dialogue saying Plex had crashed.

Anyone have any ideas? This seems to happen every 2-3 weeks, I can't seem to do anything to reliably reproduce it except for waiting.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This sounds like a networking issue, if your plex media server is taking the same ip address as your gateway it would cause this problem. When the issue occurs have you ran an ifconfig? Also is your server setup with a static ip and did you make sure to exclude the static ip from your routers dhcp scope? Does the issue still occur without plex media?